# Is it possible in prisma to filter by string length?

Tags: database, prisma

Is it possible in prisma to filter by string length?

For example, I would like to receive records whose name is 10 characters long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use [Raw Query](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access) to filter the records by string length.

Here's an example of how you could achieve it.
Considering this model

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Employee {
  employeeId Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  first_name String
  hire_date  DateTime
}
```

This query would filter out the records which have `first_name` length less than 5 characters

```js
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  log: ['query', 'info', 'warn'],
});

// A `main` function so that you can use async/await
async function main() {

  const result =
    await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM "public"."Employee" WHERE LENGTH(first_name) <= 5`;

  console.log(result);
}
main()
  .catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

Here's the output

```js
prisma:info Starting a postgresql pool with 13 connections.
prisma:query SELECT * FROM "public"."Employee" WHERE LENGTH(first_name) <= 5
[
  {
    employeeId: 1,
    first_name: 'John',
    hire_date: '2022-03-10T00:00:00+00:00'
  }
]
```